# Proving $f^{(n)} (m)$ $= 0$, the $n$th derivative of some function at $m$ is equal to zero.

Tags: derivatives, rolles-theorem

Question: Suppose some real function is differentiable $n$ times on $ℝ$. Assume that there are $n+ 1$ distinct point $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, x_{n+1}\}$ such that $ x_1 < x_2 < . . . < x_n < x_{n+1}$ and $f(x_i) = 0 $for all $i = 1, 2, . . . , n, n + 1.$ Prove that there exists at least one point $y$ such that
$f^{(n)} (y) = 0.$

First thing I know  that I probably need to use the rolles theorem due to the derivative $=0$ and since we have $f^{(n)} (y) = 0.$, I think I have to apply this theorem many times.

Definition of Rolle's theorem:

Rolle's theorem states that if a function f is continuous on the closed interval [a, b] and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$, then $f′(c) = 0$ for some $c$ within the open interval $(a, b)$

I don't know how $f(x_i) = 0 $ comes into play? And also I don't know how to "end" the proof if I apply the Rolles theorem. How do you start? Assume that a point in between (a,b) exist and then use the extreme value theorem? I am very confused. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use Rolle's Theorem to conclude that there are $n$ points such that $f' = 0$. These $n$ points each lie within the intervals $(x_1,x_2), (x_2,x_3), \dots (x_n, x_{n+1}).$ Then use the same idea to conclude that there are $n-1$ points such that $f'' = 0$. Keep this process going until you have the existence of one point $y$ such that $f^{(n)}(y) = 0$.

Comment: Hi Dionel Jaime, thanks for answering. I don't get why does $n$ points each lie within the intervals? Why does the point needs to be in the interval $(x_1, x_2)$? why the $(x_1$ and $x_2)$? Can't it be $(x_1, x_4)$ for example? and Are you saying there are $n-1$ points also lie in each intervals that specified? Many thanks again.

Comment: You just need to apply Rolle's theorem to the intervals $[x_1, x_2]$ , $[x_2,x_3]$, \dots $ [x_n,x_{n+1}]$. This gives you $n$ points for which $f'$ is $0$.

Comment: Hi Dionel Jaime, thanks for replying. What about the $f(x_i)=0$, and why are there $n-1$ points such that $f'' = 0$? Thanks for being patient with me

Comment: The fact that $f(x_i) =0$ guarantees that $f(x_i) = f(x_{i+1})  = 0$ so that we can apply Rolle's Theorem. After you apply Rolle's theorem to the intervals I mentioned, you get a set of $n$ points $c_1 \in [x_1,x_2] $ , $c_2 \in [x_2,x_3] , \dots c_n \in  , [x_n , x_{n+1}]$ so that $f'(c_i) = 0$. Then you apply Rolle's theorem again to $[c_1, c_2], \dots  ,[c_{n-1}, c_{n}]$. Then continue this process.

Comment: Hi, Dionel Jaime, thanks for the quick reply. Yeap, I finally got it, I had to reread your answers couple more times. Thank you Just one last question, if $f(x_i)=0$ for all $i=1,2,...,n,n+1$. This doesn't imply that f(x) is a straight line right since all the $x$ has the same value?

Comment: Nope. For instance $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is not a straight line despite the fact that you can find $n+1$ points for which it is equal to $0$.

Comment: Dionel Jaime, thank you so much. I understand this now thanks,